# JPA Map<User, String> mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

How can I map a Map in JPA?
I try the following mapping:

```
@ManyToMany
public Map<User, String> rsvp;
```

But I get the following errors:

```
A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: models.Event.rsvp[java.lang.String]
```

Thanks!

Comment: JPA defines support for persistence of Entity as the value, and non-Entity as the key. It doesn't explicitly define support for Entity key with non-Entity value. JDO AFAIK is the only spec allowing that. Obviously some JPA implementations may add their own support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second what DataNucleus said.

Maybe this can help you to refactor your code:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your User class is unmapped,

try adding

```
<entity class="com.path.to.user.User" />
```

into your mapping file and make sure User has an @Entity annotation

I have a similar example in my code defined as

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Map<String,Activity> activityMap= new HashMap<String, Activity>();
```

Comment: User has an @Entity annotation. I added `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, but error has not changed.